# When does a C# Task terminate?

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, task

I am working with ASP.NET. When I run a new Task, at what point will that Task terminate? Will it terminate when the thread that called it terminates? Or will it continue on until it has finished running the code within my lambda expression?

Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
Task.Run(() =>
{
    try
    {
        MyFunction();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.Write(ex);
    }
});
```

MyFunction() does not return anything, I simply want it to start running on its own so that the current thread can continue. When I run my application and call this code, it seems to work just fine. I am just trying to see if I should be worried about the task spontaneously terminating or if I will be just fine.

I also should mention that the thread that makes the request is probably going to terminate before the Task finishes.

Thanks.

Comment: Please don't ever write `catch (Exception ex)` - it's such as bad anti-pattern. Have a read of [Eric Lippert's Vexing Exceptions](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/).

Comment: @Enigmativity thats a great article! I've actually read it before. I have my exception handling like that just to show that I am doing a try catch, I didn't want to reveal anything specific to my code base as it is something I am working on at my job.

Comment: This is a design choice. It's good practice to monitor your thread for errors and there are multiple ways of doing this but it is not required. If you're confident in your method then go with it as is; possibly add some logging. As far as a task goes; this one will terminate when your application terminates otherwise it continues to run regardless of scope.

Comment: @TheGeneral  It doesn't per say, I feel like the OP is asking if the thread continues or dies with scope.  A Task, such as this one, will live as long as its in scope or referenced, the thread (if it makes one) that it runs against will run until the code is complete or until the application ends.  In which case the possible thread and Task are both ended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The task finishes its life soon after it finishes executing the code it was tasked with.
2. When the task falls out of scope it will eventually be cleaned up by the garbage collector, providing there is no code left to execute

Lastly there is no good reason why tasks should end abruptly unless an exception is thrown and cannot be caught.

.net. Doesn't roll a dice to terminate the task otherwise they would be useless. They live as long as they need to live and terminate soon after

Technically this will use a thread pool thread and it's returned to the pool, however they are just semantics

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-based-asynchronous-programming

Answer (score 0):

A `Task` may or may not have a thread but in your case of `Task.Run` it should.  You can reference the `Task` itself and it will live as long as it's in scope or you keep a living reference to it.  The thread it runs against will continue until the code completes.  It's a little confusing but know that the `Task` itself and the running thread are seperate.  A `Task`, is more like the state / manager of some work, which may or may not be on a seperate thread.  This reference can be held until the application terminates if desired where you can read the state of the work, even if it's complete.

If the `Task` leaves the scope and there is no reference the unit of work it monitors will continue; however the `Task` itself will be setup for garbage collection when this is complete.  In other words, you can fire and forget the `Task` if you want and unless there is an error or you end the application the unit of work assigned to the `Task` will complete.

Note that a `Task` will terminate with your application and if that `Task` does spawn a new thread such as you are doing with `Task.Run` it will also terminate with your application if the application ends.

Comment: Will it also terminate when it finishes executing the code assigned to the task? Or will I need to terminate it manually?

Comment: Yes. The thread will terminate and the Task will fall out of scope and become garbage collected. If the Task falls out of scope before it's complete it will still finish unless your application ends. You do not need to manually terminate the Task unless it is set to run infinitely, in which case you should OR it will terminate on it's own when the application ends.